# Alignment building blocks: in center and normal math fonts

Tags: pdftex, align, amsmath

I want a style like the 1., 2. and 5. in the figure, but make the "0" aligned in the center with the top equation.

In other words, I like the alignment of 3. in the figure, but I want the fonts to look bigger (like 1. or  2. or 5.).

So what method I can try?

[image]

The original code:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\section{test}
\label{sec:org17eb678}
\begin{enumerate}
\item using aligned:
\begin{equation}
  \psi_n=\left\{
    \begin{aligned}
      \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}sin\frac{n\pi}{2a}(x+a) &  &(|x|<a) \\
      0 & & (|x|\geq a)
    \end{aligned}
  \right.
\end{equation}

\item using flalign:
\begin{equation}
  \psi_n=\left\{
    \begin{flalign}
      \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}sin\frac{n\pi}{2a}(x+a) &  &(|x|<a) \\
      0 & & (|x|\geq a)
    \end{flalign}
  \right.
\end{equation}

\item using array:
\begin{equation}
  \psi_n=\left\{
    \begin{array}{ccl}
      \text{$\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}sin\frac{n\pi}{2a}(x+a)$} &  &(|x|<a) \\
      0 & & (|x|\geq a)
    \end{array}
  \right.
\end{equation}

\item using cases:
\begin{equation}
  \psi_n=
  \begin{cases}
    \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}sin\frac{n\pi}{2a}(x+a)  &(|x|<a) \\
    0  & (|x|\geq a)
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

\item using dcases:
\begin{equation}
  \psi_n=
  \begin{dcases}
    \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}sin\frac{n\pi}{2a}(x+a)  &(|x|<a) \\
    0  & (|x|\geq a)
  \end{dcases}
\end{equation}
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.se!  using `array` you obtain what you like. what is than your problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i guess that you looking for the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \psi_n=\left\{
    \begin{array}{c@{\qquad}l}
      \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\sin\dfrac{n\pi}{2a}(x+a) &  (|x|<a) \\[3ex]
      0 & (|x|\geq a)
    \end{array}
  \right.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is what I just need, thank you very much. Besides, add \\\[1em] will make the equation looks more beautiful.

Comment: @cwind, if answer solve your problem (on the best way), than you can accept them (by clicking on check mark at top left side of answer) :-) btw, i edit answer and add some vertical space between equation lines.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`eqparbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox)'s `\eqmakebox[<tag>][<align>]{<stuff>}` to figure out the widest element `<stuff>` under the same `<tag>`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,eqparbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \psi_n = \begin{cases}
    \eqmakebox[LHS]{$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\sin\dfrac{n \pi}{2 a}(x + a)$} & (\lvert x \rvert < a) \\
    \eqmakebox[LHS]{$0$} & (\lvert x \rvert \geq a)
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The first answer is more elegant. Anyway, thank you very much.